# how to check user permissions in snmpv3

Tags: cisco, router, cisco-ios, snmp

We have a Cisco 886 router, running IOS 15.3, which is configured with SNMP v3. The username is `testAdmin`.

Is there any command to identify, whether this user has read-only permission or read-write?

Regards,
Sumesh.

Comment: Please add router model and software version.

Comment: Cisco 886 , version 15.3

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

the command:

> show snmp user

will tell you which group the user belongs to, and the command

> show snmp group

will list the groups and the read or write views associated.

Comment: Thanks @JFL. is there any command exists to view a particular group only, instead of listing all groups?

Comment: AFAIK, no, the command show snmp group has no argument. See [this doc](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios-xml/ios/snmp/command/nm-snmp-cr-book.pdf) for all SNMP commands.